# URL Format for a PATCH that links two objects

Tags: rest, http, hypermedia

I'm not sure what the most `RESTful` + HATEOS way is to achieve my goal.

I want to use a PATCH operation to update the fields of two objects, creating a relationship between them, I'm not convinced that the current way I'm doing it is the most RESTful way of doing it.

For example,

I have an API that manages books and authors.

I have an Author entity with a list of Books.

```
{
        "authorId": 1,
        "email": "fred@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "f",
        "lastName": "red",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/authors/1",
            },
            {
                "rel": "books",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/authors/1/books",
            }
}
```

and the Book:

```
{
        "bookId": 1,
        "title": "REST is Hard",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/books/1",
            },
            {
                "rel": "author",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/authors/1",
            }
}
```

The above objects are DTOs.
I have a Spring Boot backend that manages relationships - this is only relevant in that the actual entity objects look slightly different, and are a bit leaky I think.

Currently, the API will link a book and an author together when it receives a PATCH against `http://localhost:8080/author/1/book/1`

The API will link `author/1` and `book/1` - Spring Boot adds the `book/1` entity to a list of books in the `author/1` entity and sets the `author` field of `book/1` to `author/1' - i.e this is a bidirectional one (author) to many (books) relationship.

Implementation aside (and I think there are still improvements I can make so that the implementation is better), what's the best way of forming this link via a RESTful call?

REST and HATEOS are chatty enough as it is, and I wanted to avoid having to make two URL calls (i.e. one PATCH to `author/1` and another patch to `book/1`) hence `http://localhost:8080/author/1/book/1`.

Is there a canonically right 'RESTful' way of doing this? How would you implement this?

Comment: I feel like you only need to add a relation to Author on the edited book. What do you think about it?

Comment: I did think about that @AlbanDericbourg - part of the current approach is actually also laziness now that I think about it. With this request I can just put things in the URL and not have to manage any request body, serialization etc

Comment: First, the characters and structure of the URI shouldn't be of importance to a client as the URI should be provided by the server anyways and a client shouldn't parse or interpret such a URI to start with. Next, [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) does provide links to registered HTTP methods including links to the RFC proposing these methods. One of these methods is [LINK](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068#section-19.6.1.2) that basically does what you want to do, even though it is defined in an "ancient" HTTP 1.1 RFC